# What is the principal argument of $\frac{4-z_0-\bar z_0}{z_0-\bar z_0+2i} $under the given conditions?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

> Let $S$ be the set of all complex numbers $z$ satisfying $\vert
>  z-2+i\vert\ge\sqrt 5.$If the complex number $z_0$ is  such that
> $\frac{1}{\vert z_0-1\vert}$ is the maximum of the set
> $\{\frac{1}{\vert z-1\vert}:z\in S\}$,then the principal argument of
> $\frac{4-z_0-\bar z_0}{z_0-\bar z_0+2i}$ is -
>
> (A)$\frac{-\pi}{2}$
> (B)$\frac{\pi}{4}$
> (C)$\frac{\pi}{2}$
> (D)$\frac{3\pi}{4}$

### Solution

- $\vert z-2+i\vert\ge \sqrt 5\implies \vert z-(2-i)\vert\implies \vert
     (x+iy)-(2-i)\vert\ge \sqrt 5\implies (x-2)^2+(y+1)^2\ge \sqrt
     5\implies (x-2)^2+(y+1)^2\ge (5)^{1/4}$
- $\frac{1}{\vert z_0-1\vert}$ is the maximum of the set
  $\{\frac{1}{\vert z-1\vert}:z\in S\}$ $\implies \frac{1}{\vert z-1\vert}\le \frac{1}{\vert z_0-1\vert}\implies \frac{1}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\le \frac{1}{(x_0-1)^2+y_0^{2}}$

From here i'm not getting how to proceed further. Please provide some hint. This question was asked in JEE(ADVANCED)$2019$ PAPER 1 is Mathematics section. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of the circle is at $2 - i$. The point on the circle closest to $1$ lies on the line through $2 - i$ and $1$, therefore $\operatorname{Im} z_0 = 1 - \operatorname{Re} z_0$ and
$$\frac {4 - z_0 - \overline {z_0}} {z_0 - \overline {z_0} + 2 i} = -i.$$

Comment: :I'm not getting "The point on the circle closest to 1 lies on the line through $2−i$ and $1$, therefore $\operatorname{Im} z_0 = 1 - \operatorname{Re} z_0$".How does $"1"$ in second line comes into picture?

Comment: The equation of the straight line through the points $(2, -1)$ and $(1, 0)$ is $y = 1 - x$. $z_0$ is located on that line.

Comment: :$ \frac{1}{\vert z-1\vert}\le \frac{1}{\vert z_0-1\vert}\implies \vert z_0-1\vert\le \vert z-1\vert$.It means the distance of every point lying outside the given circle, $\vert z-2-i\vert=5^{1/4}$ from 1 is greater then the distance of $z_0$ from 1.From this, can we conclude that $z_0=1?$

Comment: :How have you guessed that $z_0$  is located on  line,$y=1-x?$.

Comment: $z_0$ is certainly not equal to $1$. You have the point $(1, 0)$ and the circle with radius $\sqrt 5$ centered at $(2, -1)$. Solve the geometric problem of finding the point on the circle closest to the given point. Then show that the distance to all other points in $S$ is larger.